# inet_ntoa gives the same result when called with two different addresses

Tags: c, printf

```
//
char ip1[] = "127.0.0.1";
char ip2[] = "211.100.21.179";
printf("ip1: %s\nip2: %s\n", ip1, ip2);

// 
long l1 = inet_addr(ip1);
long l2 = inet_addr(ip2);
printf("ip1: %ld\nip2: %ld\n", l1, l2);

//
struct in_addr addr1, addr2;
memcpy(&addr1, &l1, 4);
memcpy(&addr2, &l2, 4);
printf("%u\n", addr1.s_addr);
printf("%u\n", addr2.s_addr);

//
printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr1));
printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr2));

//
printf("%u,%s\n", addr1.s_addr, inet_ntoa(addr1));
printf("%u,%s\n", addr2.s_addr, inet_ntoa(addr2));
printf("%s <--> %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr1), inet_ntoa(addr2));
```

The output is:

```
ip1: 127.0.0.1
ip2: 211.100.21.179
ip1: 16777343
ip2: 3004523731
16777343
3004523731
127.0.0.1
211.100.21.179
16777343,127.0.0.1
3004523731,211.100.21.179
211.100.21.179 <--> 211.100.21.179    // why the same??
```

I know `printf` parse arg from right to left or vise versa is platform-dependent, but why the output is the same value, please help to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Linux man pages : https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given
>   in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.
>   The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which
>   subsequent calls will overwrite.

It seems the two calls the `inet_nota()` share a buffer, so calling the function twice overwrites whats in the buffer and replaces it with the next call, thus you get the same output

Answer (score 1):

`inet_ntoa()` uses an internal buffer to convert an address to a string.  Every time you call it it rewrites the same buffer with the new address.  So both calls to `inet_ntoa()` are returning the same pointer, and thus `printf()` prints the same string twice.  inet_ntoa() does this so that you don't have to `free()` a string every time you call it.  If you want your output to look the way you expect you can do this:

```
 printf("%s <--> ", inet_ntoa(addr1))
 printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr2));
```

That way `printf()` will have printed the first address before the second call to `inet_ntoa()` overwrites it.